# Custom Navigation Toolbar text

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want the HStack containing the "S M T W..." to have the same background color as the navigation bar, but ONLY when it is at the top of the screen

[image]

Right now it sticks perfectly fine, but background is not

Here is my CalendarView code where I just added my letters in asection, so when user scrolls it sticks to the navigation bar

```
struct CalendarMain<DateView>: View where DateView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
    
    @EnvironmentObject var calendarViewModel: CalendarViewModel
    
    let dayLetters = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"] // Here is my day letters
    
    let interval: DateInterval
    let content: (Date) -> DateView
    
    init(interval: DateInterval, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Date) -> DateView) {
        self.interval = interval
        self.content = content
    }
    
    private var months: [Date] {
        calendar.generateDates(
            inside: interval,
            matching: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)
        )
    }
    
    @State private var firstAppear = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack(pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                    Section {
                        // some non important code
                        }
                    } header: {
                        HStack {
                           // here I adding them to the top of NavigationStack toolbar
                            ForEach(0..<dayLetters.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                Text(dayLetters[index])
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Scroll to todays Month
                if firstAppear {
                    firstAppear = false
                    value.scrollTo(isMonthToday(), anchor: .center)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: calendarViewModel.selectedDay) { selectedDay in
                // Scroll to selectedDay day
                guard let selectedDay = selectedDay else { return }
                
                withAnimation {
                    // Scroll to selected date cell
                    value.scrollTo(selectedDay.date.description, anchor: .trailing)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func isMonthToday() -> Date {
        for month in months {
            if Calendar.current.isDate(Date(), equalTo: month, toGranularity: .month) {
                return month
            }
        }
        
        return months[0]
    }
}
```